# Program crashed after end of scope

Tags: c++, vector

I was confused from this following codes, it's creating crash that I fully don't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Store
{
    int pos;
    char character;
};

vector<struct Store> v_store;

void swap_inside_vector(vector<struct Store> &v_store, int a, int b)
{
    struct Store tmp = v_store[b];
    v_store[b] = v_store[a];
    v_store[a] = tmp;
}

int find_inside_vector(vector<struct Store> &v_store, int pos)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v_store.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v_store[i].pos == pos)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

void swap_most_right_to_most_left(vector<struct Store> &v_store)
{
    struct Store tmp = v_store[v_store.size() - 1];

    for(int i = v_store.size(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        v_store[i] = v_store[i-1];
    }

    v_store[0] = tmp;
}

void print_char_inside_vector(vector<struct Store> &v) // used for debugging
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%C", v[i].character);
    }
}

int check_vector_original_state(vector<struct Store> &v_store)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= v_store.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v_store[i-1].pos != i)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    char input_str[100];

    for(int q = 1; scanf("\n%d", &n), n; q++)
    {
        scanf("%s", input_str); 

        vector<struct Store> original_store, tmp_origin_store, v_store;
        vector<vector<struct Store> > store_vector;

        original_store.clear();
        tmp_origin_store.clear();
        v_store.clear();
        store_vector.clear();

        for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(input_str); i++)
        {
            struct Store s = {.pos = i, .character = input_str[i-1]};
            original_store.push_back(s);
        }

        tmp_origin_store = original_store;
        v_store = tmp_origin_store;

        for(int i = 1, current_pos = 0; i <= n; i++, current_pos++)
        {
            int vector_index = find_inside_vector(v_store, tmp_origin_store[current_pos].pos);

            //printf("Processing -> [%d], Current Pos -> [%d]\n", i, current_pos);

            for(int z = 0; z < (current_pos + 1); z++)
            {
                if(vector_index == (v_store.size() - 1))
                {
                    swap_most_right_to_most_left(v_store);
                    vector_index = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    swap_inside_vector(v_store, vector_index, vector_index + 1);
                    vector_index++;
                }

                //print_char_inside_vector(v_store);
                //puts("");
            }

            //puts("");

            store_vector.push_back(v_store);

            if(check_vector_original_state(v_store))
            {
                store_vector.push_back(v_store);
                break;
            }

            if(current_pos == (v_store.size() - 1))
            {
                tmp_origin_store = v_store;
                current_pos = -1;
            }
        }

        // debugging
        /*for(int x = 0; x < store_vector.size(); x++)
        {
            printf("[%d] -> ", x + 1);
            print_char_inside_vector(store_vector[x]);
            puts("");
        }*/

        int target_pos;

        if(store_vector.size() < n)
        {
            target_pos = n % store_vector.size();
        }
        else
        {
            target_pos = store_vector.size();
        }

        if(target_pos == 0)
        {
            printf("%d. ", q);
            print_char_inside_vector(store_vector[0]);
            puts("");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d. ", q);
            print_char_inside_vector(store_vector[target_pos - 1]);
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

What this program does is accepting input from STDIN, process it, and output it on STDOUT.

My expecting input is

```
3 ABCD
13 ACM
3 DAEQD
4 FAEQS
```

Expected output is

```
1. CABD
2. CAM
3. DAQDE
4. FQASE
```

My problem is, after inputing fourth input into STDIN, and after output is being shown, crash occured.

```
C:\Study>h.exe
3 ABCD
1. CABD
13 ACM
2. CAM
3 DAEQD
3. DAQDE
4 FAEQS
4. FQASE
      0 [main] h 9092 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to h.exe.stackdump
```

From my observation, I think the problem is at the vector, but it's just a guess.

Comment: In C++ you don't need `struct Store` everywhere you use it.  You should use a debugger to see where the crash is and what causes it.

Comment: [disadvantages of scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Comment: This loop`for(int i = v_store.size(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        v_store[i] = v_store[i-1];
    }`   has definitely problems. It starts at size() whereas the largest index of vector is size()-1

Comment: Also, this code would be greatly reduced in size if you just used the algorithm functions instead of these full-blown functions you've coded.  For example `std::swap(v_store[vector_index], v_store[vector_index + 1]);` is all you need to swap two `Stores`.

Comment: As the comment previous to mine stated, you should get out of the habit of starting your loops at 1 or at `size`.  In C++, array and vector indices start at 0, not 1.  If you kept that in mind when writing your code, you would reduce the chance of going out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code didn't compile :

```
//struct Store s = { .pos = i, .character = input_str[i - 1] }; // syntax not recongnized 
Store s = { i, input_str[i - 1] };   // replaced with this.
```

After fixing this, the debugging immediatly identified an out of bound problem on a vector, which could lead to memory corruption issue. It's in `swap_most_right_to_most_left()`:

```
for (int i = v_store.size(); i > 0; i--)  {  // you start with i=v_store.size() 
    v_store[i] = v_store[i - 1];             // and you immediately get out of bounds !  
}
```

If you correct this instruction to :

```
for (int i = v_store.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
    v_store[i] = v_store[i - 1];
}
```

you'll get the expected output for the given input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction, what debugger are you currently use now? :-)

Comment: MSVC 2013 - when you choose "debuging build", the code gets compiled with some nice tricks to detect runtime problems like memory corruption, and a lot of extra asserts in the libraries.